# How to specify length of undefined array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, tdd

I am just beginning to learn TypeScript and am working on some TDD stuff. In my model file I have a prop called 'innovatorQuotes' that is an array (made up of strings) that I want to have a specific length of 3. I can't figure out how to achieve this. Here is the current line:

`innovatorQuotes: types.optional(types.array(types.string), []),`

How can I set the expected length to 3? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The short answer is [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) But this doesn't look like types at all. This looks some sort of schema building library. Where does the `types` object come from that you are accessing to build up this schema? What library is that?

Comment: @AlexWayne we are using Mobx.

Comment: According to [this github issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree/issues/805) I don't think MobX supports this out of the box currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
innovatorQuotes: [string, string, string]
```

But remember TypeScript doesn't apply to runtime, it can only ensure you don't define an array of different length, but if you do .push etc... it won't be able to recognize it's exceeding the length.